# prolog traverse nonstandard tree left to right

Tags: tree, prolog, tree-traversal

I need to implement a predicate `trav(Tree,List)` that performs a left to
right tree traversal;

Where: Tree is defined by the structure node(left,right), where left and right can be either another node or any Prolog data item. List is the list of leaf node values in the tree.

For example:

```
?- trav(x,L).
L = [x].
?- trav(node(1,node(2,node(a,b))),L).
L = [1, 2, a, b] .
```

What I have so far:

```
trav(tree,[ ]).
trav(node(Left,Rigth), L) :-
    trav(Left, L),
    trav(Right, L),
    append(Left,[Left|Right],L).
```

Comment: You have again a problem with what you want a tree to be! Define **first** a predicate `is_tree/1` that states what a tree is in you opinion. It is *very* uncommon, but certainly possible to have nodes without elements. Such nodes typically occur for expression-trees. But otherwise they do not occur.

Comment: Not my opinion, it is what I was given to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Prolog is slightly rusty, but I believe that this should do it:

```
node(Left, Right).

trav(node(Left, Right), L) :- 
  trav(Left, L1), 
  trav(Right, L2),
  append(L1, L2, L).
trav(X, [X]) :- X \= node(A, B).
```

Intuitively, `trav(Left, L1)` says traverse the left subtree, storing each element in `L1`.  `trav(Right, L2)` says traverse the right subtree storing each element in `L2`.  Lastly, `append(L1, L2, L)` append the two lists, `L1 and L2` into list `L`.  For a leaf, `trav(X, [X])`, puts `X` into a singleton list as long as it does not unify with a `node`.

Comment: Is it correct to stop it after it prints the first line, if so how or where do you place the cut?

`1 ?- trav(node(1,node(2,node(a,b))),L).


L = [1, 2, a, b] ;


L = [1, 2, node(a, b)] ;


L = [1, node(2, node(a, b))] ;


L = [node(1, node(2, node(a, b)))].`

Comment: Is it OK to explicitly annotate the leaves of the tree?  So, your query would look more like: `trav(node(leaf(1),node(leaf(2),node(leaf(a),leaf(b)))),L).`  This will only have one solution in my edited answer.

Comment: The examples that I provided above are what will be used!

Comment: OK @user3633383, this should do it